# PyDev/Eclipse do not complain if class object do no exist

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a python lib.py containing a class

```
class myClass():
    myVar = 1
    def myFunc(self):
        return 0
```

In Eclipse/PyDev I import this package

```
import lib

a = lib.myClass
b = a.myFunc()
c = a.myVar
d = lib.otherClass  # complains
e = lib.myClass.otherVar  # does not complain
```

I would like PyDev to complain at code analysis when a class object doesn't exist but it do not. There is no problem of import since I can see the class object and function with code completion and it recognizes `lib.myClass` when hovered.

Answer (score 0):

this is expected... some of the checks that have a higher false positive count or are slower to computed are not added on purpose (in this case, this particular check has a high false positive count due to the dynamic nature of Python and the limitations inherent of doing a static analysis of Python code).

Now, having said that, I believe PyLint (https://www.pylint.org/) does that and PyDev does integrate nicely with PyLint. If you're interested, see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html for details on using PyLint with PyDev.